# How to force a link to use specific route (MVC routing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these two routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default2", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{OrderId}/{CustomerID}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "NorthwindOrders", action = "Index", OrderId = UrlParameter.Optional, CustomerID = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and want to create link that uses the second route.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should probably reverse those two as both the second parameters are optional (same with the id parameter above) that the first URL will always match first. Even then any link that matches the "Default" one will also match the "Default2" so you should probably make OrderId and CustomerId required (or at least OrderId

Comment: when you use Html.ActionLink, you can specify the Route Name to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specifically use a route, you can use the Html helper `Html.RouteLink` :

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("my link", "Default2", new {OrderId=1, CustomerId=2}) %>
```

Also, you can put the second route first : the most generic route should be at the end, in order to be used only when no specific route was found.

Answer (score 0):

Order is very important w/ MapRoutes.  Try reversing the order of those two statements.

Answer (score 0):

As well you should use definition of routes in different order.
the order should be more specific first to less

also in your action links i would add routing parameters

Answer (score 0):

Actually not 100% what the OP asked for, but what I needed was an ActionResult that forcefully uses a specific route. `RedirectToAction` always used the wrong route. I found it in `RedirectToRoute("RouteName", new { action="Index" })`.